# getting error in generator active_admin:resource -> key: '_manager_session'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

i want to resolve this error, anyone please, this error is about syntax error in session_store.rb file, at attachment in pastie:

http://pastie.org/2681282

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use Ruby 1.9-style Hash syntax (`key: value`) in Ruby 1.8. Either upgrade to Ruby 1.9 or change your code to use the Hash syntax supported in Ruby 1.8, i.e. `:key => '_manager_session'`.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout my answer here:
[Mac OSX Snow Leopard - Rails error: Session_store.rb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698319/99000)