# Syntax error when creating a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am creating Car model in Rails 3 by using command:

```
rails generate model Car name:string id_str:string
```

but I got the error:

```
/home/XX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /home/XX/myapp/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

why?

my `session_store.rb`

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

What's wrong with my `session_store.rb`?

Comment: Your `session_store.rb` contains `key: '_myapp_session'` but the error displays `key: '_deptracker_session'`. Are you sure you pasted the right file?

Comment: Yes, it is my typo, I corrected it now

Comment: post whole file, as listed example contains no errors, some non-closed statement is above

Comment: I just created a new Rails project, and go the same error. The file session_store.rb contains the line `Demo::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_demo_session'` only.

Answer (score 7):

This error usually happens when you are trying to use the Ruby 1.9.2 Hash syntax with Ruby < 1.9.

In Ruby 1.9.2 the following code works perfectly

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session'
```

while in Ruby < 1.9 you must use

```
Myapp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_myapp_session'
```

This is strange, because your stack trace references Ruby 1.9.2. Are you sure you are running the generator with Ruby 1.9.2?

In any case, you can convert your `session_store.rb` file to the hash-rocket syntax. If it works, it means you are not using Ruby 1.9.2 and you pasted an invalid error message.

Comment: my "ruby -v" shows me I am using ruby 1.9.2p290, very strange I got the problem

Comment: yes it works after I changed the syntax but I am using 1.9.2...strange

Comment: Curious to know how this was solved - I'm experiencing the same issue on snow leopard, adding the => solved the issue for just that file but keeps causing errors in other files.

Comment: @TeckniX It means you're not using Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @Simone Carletti - Right as you can see below, I had to go through a LOT to get the correct version of ruby to load. The issue was the same as the original poster, where 2 versions of ruby are installed, yet you don't know why it's not using the one you want.

Comment: I got the same error -- using 1.9.2 but it's seems as if `rails g migration` thinks Ruby < 1.9 is loaded. But the stack trace shows me that I really am using `1.9`.

Answer (score 3):

Well through a bit of debugging and playing around, this is what I ended up doing:

```
for x in `gem list --no-versions`; do sudo gem uninstall $x; done
```

This forces all 'old' gems to be removed. I then proceeded to verify the gem environment to confirm that gem was using the correct ruby version:

```
sudo gem env
```

The error experienced is due to the fact that rails is still trying to use ruby 1.8, which causes all sorts of issues.

Once all of the above checks out properly do:

```
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install rubygems-update
sudo update_rubygems
```

Which will make sure that you are at the latest gem version. Then:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

This will install everything you need. I ran all of the gem commands as sudo, to make sure that my root install was properly configured/setup.

Your final gem env should look something like:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.13
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
```

Comment: You can also rename /usr/bin/ruby to something like /usr/bin/ruby-1.8 and create a symlink to the new ruby via: sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: Last update which made everything work perfectly - Edit your rails file via: sudo vi /usr/bin/rails (other editor work here too) and replace the first line of #!/System/.... by #!/usr/bin/ruby  - This will force rails to use the symlink we created above instead of using the default Snow Leopard ruby 1.8 framework

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: uninstall then reinstall the railties gem

**Long answer**:

In your project directory, if you type in `which rails`, what do you see? On mine, I saw `/usr/bin/rails`. This gave me a clue that it's using the wrong `rails` executable. If I look at my `$PATH`, I can see that RVM's bin path (`/Users/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin`) did not contain the `rails` file (as to how this got deleted -- I don't have a clue). That must have been why the `/usr/bin/rails` got picked up by my system instead.

Looking at the Rails source, I saw that the `railties` gem has the `rails` bin file. I uninstalled railties (`gem uninstall railties`), then reinstalled it again. Voila - `which rails` shows `/Users/ramon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding an .rvmrc file to my application.

```
echo "rvm ruby-2.0.0@rails32 --create" > .rvmrc
```

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this by deleting my ~/.rvm directory and reinstalling RVM.

Answer (score -2):

really strange question as error is self decribing

you have some mess in this file, and missing end statement

```
`load': /home/XX/myapp/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3
```

Comment: Yes, I see, but where is wrong in my session_store.rb, (check my updated post)