# Error running rails server - how can I change default ruby for rubygem environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

So I came across this question ( [Syntax error when creating a Rails model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753021/syntax-error-when-creating-a-rails-model) )  which has an error similar to mine. I am deducing from it that my problem is using Ruby 1.8 instead of 1.9. I tried uninstalling the gems and updating rubygems as described in one of the answers, but that did not fix the issue. I also tried setting the default ruby via rvm to 1.9 - it works but it does not solve the issue.

When I run "gem env" I get the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/owner/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

In usr/bin I have a "ruby" which is a symlink to usr/bin/ruby1.9.1.

Basically, **I need to know how to change the ruby being used here (at least I think that will solve my issue).**

My OS is Linux Mint 12.
Rails --version returns "Rails 3.2.3"

My full error is below (from running "rails s" in project directory):

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_sample_app_session'
                              ^
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5
    from /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config.ru:4
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /media/Windows/Users/Owner/Projects/rails_projects/sample_app/config.ru:1
```

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'tilt'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  # System-dependent gems# Test gems on Windows
    group :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
    gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
    gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
    end 
    gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
    gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

PATH:

> echo $PATH
>   /usr/bin/rubycurrent:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

"which ruby" returns:

```
/usr/bin/rubycurrent/ruby
```

Comment: you can use rvm to manage ur ruby version

Comment: @Kit Ho As stated, I tried to change the default version via rvm, and it works, but I still have the same issue. "rvm list default" returns "ruby-1.9.3-p194".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally figure it out. Here's what I did.

First, to troubleshoot I uninstalled ruby 1.8. After that I tried running **rails s** again and got the following error:

```
 bash: /usr/local/bin/rails: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

When I checked **/usr/local/bin/rails** script I saw it was including **/usr/bin/ruby1.8** at the top. After trying tons of different things to get it working, the only thing that worked was uninstalling ruby, rubygems, rails, and rvm, and reinstalling them all (I had to do this several times... finally it worked one time).

You can try what is listed below to see if it works for you:
http://fatal-errors.com/ubuntu-10-ruby-1-9-rails-3-not-working-solved/99008.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your terminal configuration file (~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc, etc.) and make sure that the directory that contains ruby 1.9 occurs in the path variable before /usr/bin. In general it is not good to modify /usr/bin because things in here are usually system dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't seem to work. Those two files are empty, and adding ruby 1.9 directory to the front of PATH (via the terminal) didn't work either.

Comment: Those two files aren't necessarily your shell configuration. What shell are you using?

Comment: What about the file ~/.bash_profile, is that empty? Here is what I would do. Edit ~/.bash_profile. Even if it is empty, add the line `export PATH=[ruby 1.9 path]:$PATH`. Replace [ruby 1.9 path] with something like /usr/local/bin or wherever ruby 1.9 is installed. Then in bash, run `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: I realized both files ruby1.8 and ruby1.9.1 are in /usr/bin. What I did is make a copy of ruby1.9.1 as "ruby" and put it in /usr/bin/rubycurrent. I then added this path to .bash_profile (output appended to question). After all that, same error.