# Ruby on Rails syncing application folders via Dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, localhost, dropbox

I have been syncing my /Sites folder via Symlinks on Dropbox between my home computer and my Laptop.  Its an iMac and a MAcbook Pro both with identical usernames, software versions etc...  Its been working like a charm.  However I just started developing with RoR and I am running into an issue because of something to do with the way the apps store session data.  So when I try to run the rails server in my Macbook in the application directory, I get this:

```
USERNAME[~/sites/rails/blog]rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /Users/USERNAME/Sites/Rails/blog/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_blog_session'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get around this? Is there some way to refresh something somewhere when I fire up the current computer so as to make this ok?

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)` means a ruby version error, are you sure that the ruby version is the same in both machines?

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753021/syntax-error-when-creating-a-rails-model